# Get article image when shared from safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-share-extension

Our team is building an iOS application. We have a requirement like to share a link from browser like safari. From the application we are getting the URL shared from the browser but we also need to get the main article image(if available) or the snapshot of the the page. We need to show this image somewhere in the application.

Is someone have experience/idea on this implementation? Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to find a way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: well, I found a third party framework called [embed.ly](http://embed.ly)
I used that framework in the backend service to get the required info from the url I received from the iOS application.